# what is meanging of gcc option "-fmessage-length"?

Tags: c++, c, gcc, compiler-construction

I am using CDT(eclipse for c language). I found that default gcc compiler options are `-O0 -g3 -Wall -c -fmessage-length=0`. what's the meaning of `-fmessage-length`? that should be `-fflag`, but what about `message-length`? I didnt find it in [GCC Command-Line Options](http://tigcc.ticalc.org/doc/comopts.html). Thanks for your consideration.

Comment: http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc-4.0.0/gcc/Language-Independent-Options.html#Language-Independent-Options

Answer (score 42, accepted):

> I didnt find it in GCC Command-Line Options.

That's because you're looking at ["a *modified version* of the Command-Line Options section of the GCC Manual."](http://tigcc.ticalc.org/doc/comopts.html)

[This is the *official* list of all possible GCC command-line options](http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Option-Index.html), which leads to this section: ["3.7 Options to Control Diagnostic Messages Formatting"](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Diagnostic-Message-Formatting-Options.html#Diagnostic-Message-Formatting-Options). This is what the section has to say:

> **3.7 Options to Control Diagnostic Messages Formatting**
>
> Traditionally, diagnostic messages have been formatted irrespective of
>   the output device's aspect (e.g. its width, ...). You can use the
>   options described below to control the formatting algorithm for
>   diagnostic messages, e.g. how many characters per line, how often
>   source location information should be reported. Note that some
>   language front ends may not honor these options.
>
> *-fmessage-length=n*
>
> Try to format error messages so that they fit on lines of about n characters. The default is 72 characters for g++ and 0 for the rest of the front ends supported by GCC. If n is zero, then
>   no line-wrapping is done; each error message appears on a single line.
>
> ...

Answer (score 10):

man page for gcc says

```
-fmessage-length=n
       Try to format error messages so that they fit on lines of about n characters.  The default is 72 characters for g++ and 0 for the rest of the front ends supported by GCC.  If n is
       zero, then no line-wrapping will be done; each error message will appear on a single line.
```

Just a formatting option for error messages.